# why is main(args: Array<String>) allowed to be defined in more than one file

Tags: kotlin

I have defined main(args: Array) in two Kotlin files in the same package. The compiler does not complain. Why not?
I am using IntelliJ IDEA with Gradle

```
#file1.kt
package test
fun main(args: Array<String>) {}

#file2.kt
package test
fun main(args: Array<String>) {}
```

Comment: Why should it complain? These are two separate entry points... if you want to run the program you need to know exactly which one you want to use.

Comment: @Moira Suppose you want to call one of them from a class in another package, how would you import it and make sure you don't import the other one? Other functions than main do cause an ambiguity error.

Comment: @Moira Can we define main() in the 2 files? Answer is not.

Comment: this main function is not allowed either. fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    launch { println("main") }
}

Comment: It's not supposed to complain when you have it in two different files. You can do the same with Java, because the main function always points to a Java class, ***not*** a package. The code compiles to `file[num]Kt.java`, which means two separate classes. It's by design, and is also valid in Java

Comment: @ Zoe In Java, the main function is inside the class. However, the main() function in Kotin is top level. Also, fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking { launch { println("main") } }  and fun main() are not allowed.  It creates so much confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Would the compiler complain if it was Java? No.
Since main method is an entry point to your application, the problem can arise only when there is ambiguity in the application that you are trying to compose. In your question, you haven't provided any specifics about your application. Those 2 files can be completely unaware of each other for what it's worth.

It can be a problem at startup, but even that would rarely happen these days. Modern frameworks, like Spring Boot, have their own way to identify where to start your application, that is where the entry point is.
They make use of their specific MANIFEST files and context/class loaders and project structures.

Comment: It is different in Java. The main method in Java is defined inside the class. Here in Kotlin, the main function is top level.  Also I do mention the 2 files are in the same package. Even though developers may not be aware it, the compiler will. Try define main() in both files to see what happens.

Comment: I did try to add a file beside my main application file and it still compiles and works without problem. You should provide more context probably. Everything compiles down to Java classes, the only difference with Kotlin is that the classes will have "Kt" in the end.

Comment: did you try main() in the 2 files?  I mean main(), not main(args: Array<String>)

Comment: Ah, got your point. But still, the problems only happen when I try to build a Spring Boot executable by calling bootRun or bootJar. If I only run gradle compileKotlin everything if fine. So we are back to the questions "Why should Kotlin compiler bother?"